# PostgreSQL formatting time aggregate function date('date_format')

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is there any aggregate function to format date & time (however I am interested in interval more) in a custom way like `11:10:45` to `11h 10m 45s` or something like that in PostgreSQL ? or I need to extract the parts or concat them by myself ?

Problem occurs specially with `number of days` in `interval`

Comment: Why do you need aggregate function? Could you post your SQL here?

Comment: I assume that "aggregate" in the question is just a misunderstanding and the OP is looking for a plain function.

Comment: actually I thought there already is some functin like `AVG()` or `SUM()` for this purpose. So I kept an aggregate there. should I remove that from title ?

Comment: what would the aggregate function have to do? Compute the interval between the first an the last timestamp in the set? Maybe show an example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the full documentation for the to_char function, it can do what you want

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Yes but would they work same in interval too ? What If I want to get `number of days` in interval. where as `DDD` returns `day of year (001-366)`

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in number of days formatter.  You'll need to build it up from the seconds using `(extract(epoch from interval '3days') / (24*3600))::int` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear. If you want to retrieve the

> number of days in interval

You can use [`EXTRACT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day from '7 week'::interval) AS d

 d
----
 49
```

Note that this extracts a *subfield* of an interval as given. the interval is not normalized or justified. To justify the interval first use [`justify_interval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day from justify_interval('7 week'::interval)) AS d;

 d
----
 19
```

A month of 30 days has been deducted from the 49 days.

Accordingly these expressions return 0 days:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day from '24h'::interval);
SELECT EXTRACT(day from '1 months'::interval);
```

---

If you just want the **number of days that lie between dates**:

```
SELECT '2012-3-23'::date - '2012-3-1'::date AS d;

 d
----
 22
```

You can just subtract dates to get an integer signifying the number of days in between.

Or between timestamps:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (day from '2012-03-25 23:12'::timestamp
                       - '2010-03-01 03:34'::timestamp) AS d;

  d
-----
 755
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting different values of the PostgreSQL setting *intervalstyle*:

```
db=# show intervalstyle ;
 IntervalStyle 
---------------
 postgres

db=# select interval '3 days 11:10:45';
    interval     
-----------------
 3 days 11:10:45

db=# set intervalstyle = 'postgres_verbose';
SET

db=# select interval '3 days 11:10:45';
             interval              
-----------------------------------
 @ 3 days 11 hours 10 mins 45 secs

db=# set intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
SET

db=# select interval '3 days 11:10:45';
   interval    
---------------
 P3DT11H10M45S
```